# How to remove or hide the previously selected value of a combo box from the list that are displayed under the combo box in Windows Form?

Tags: c#, winforms

I was just playing with combo box value and was trying something new. I just wanted to know how should I remove or hide the already selected value of a combo box the next time i use this combo box. I mean once I have selected a value from a combo box, I would not be able to see that selected value again when I click the combo box the next time. I have the following values in the combo box A

```
List<string> comboList = new List<string>();
        comboList .Add("--Please Select--");
        comboList .Add("ABC");
        comboList .Add("DEF");
        comboList .Add("GHI");
        comboList .Add("JKL");
        comboList .Add("MNO");
        cmbNewComboBox.DataSource = comboList.DeepCopy();
```

if I select value "ABC" from the cmbNewComboBox and click ok, then I would not be getting this value again in this combobox. i.e, the values that will be displayed in the combobox will be only "DEF, GHI, JKL, MNO" BUT NOT "ABC"

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
 if(cmbNewComboBox.SelectedIndex != -1)
         comboList.Remove(cb01.SelectedItem.ToString());
```

Comment: Then you are doing something wrong. The ComboBox-Control provides a "Remove" property.

Comment: Do you have this reference System.Collections.Generic?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
private void combobox1_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int iIndex;
    if (int.tryParse(combobox1.Tag, out iIndex))
    {
        if (iIndex > -1)
            ((List<string>)combobox1.DataSource).RemoveAt(iIndex);
    }
    combobox1.Tag = combobox1.SelectedIndex;
}
```